# Firebird does not improve upon index creating on varying character column

Tags: sql, firebird

the column has data like

```
contract_id 
02/2006
00102006
null
00102080
```

When I perform a query that uses this
C.contract_id like '00072017%'

It doesn't change a thing.

I've tried

```
CREATE INDEX teste_chamado ON table contract_id
```

and

```
create index idx_table1_col1_8 on table
computed by (substring(contract_id from 1 for 8));
```

the later gave 1s improvement. It was taking originally 17s

Answer (score 2):

The first index you show is invalid syntax as it is missing the column list.

The second index you defined cannot be used for the condition `C.contract_id like '00072017%'` as it doesn't include the expression, so the performance improvement you observed is more likely attributable to caching effects.

If you want to use an index for `C.contract_id like '00072017%'`, then you should create an index

```sql
create index idx_table1_col1_8 on table (contract_id)
```

This does assume that you literally use `C.contract_id like '00072017%'`, and not a parameter for the `LIKE` because with parameters it cannot use the index (if you need parameters, then use `STARTING WITH` instead of `LIKE` and leave out the wildcard).

To use your current expression index, you need to use the condition

```sql
substring(C.contract_id from 1 for 8) = '00072017'
```